# Issues with local query sorting

Tags: breeze

I've encountered problems with sorting and `executeQueryLocally()`.

**Some examples:**

- Sorting on a property with a name of "Group" **does** work: `.orderBy("Group");`
- Sorting on a property with a name of "Name" **does NOT** work: `.orderBy("Name");` In this case, no error is raised but the array is not sorted.
- Sorting on both "Group and Name" **does** work: `.orderBy("Group, Name");`
- Sorting on any of the above with "desc" **does NOT** work: `.orderBy("Group desc");` 
  In this case, an error like the following is raised: `Object Group1 has no method 'getProperty'`

Unfortunately I haven't had a chance to debug the comparer to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "orderBy" clause with a "desc" qualification is now fixed in v 0.73.5, available either via nuget or on the breeze website.

Comment: Should be fixed now. If Jay's answer (and fix) satisfied you, please click the tick mark under the up/down to indicate that you accept it. If not, let us know and we'll keep digging. Thx

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like we are all set.  Even .orderBy("Name") is now working.  Not sure if you did anything to address that or perhaps there was some other issue on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I work on the *breeze* product.

I was unable to reproduce your first error

- Sorting on a property with a name of "Name" does NOT work: .orderBy("Name"); In this case, no error is raised but the array is not sorted.

but I was able to reproduce your 2nd error.

- Sorting on any of the above with "desc" does NOT work: .orderBy("Group desc"); In this case, an error like the following is raised: Object Group1 has no method 'getProperty'

I will try to get a fix out for this one sometime tomorrow.

If you can give me more context on the first error, I will take another look at it as well.

and ... thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Group is a keyword, and you must wrap it by [] or ''